# Apache POI 3.10.1: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.10.1 library to read an Excel file that has the suffix of `.xlsx`, and below is part of the code that initializes the workbook for the file, but I keep getting this error:

```
Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

**my relevant code:**

```
            File dbFile = new File("/path/to/the/excel.xlsx");
            InputStream dbInFileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(dbPath));
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = null;

            try {
//              workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(dbInFileStream);  // this does not work
                workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(dbInFileStream); // this is the cause for the above error
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch(InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried to read the API for POI 3.10.1, and it seems that WorkbookFactor.create() requires a bytecode array, but I'm not sure how to convert the inputstream to byteArray. Could someone help with this? Thanks

Comment: Please look at your code. You are creating a File dbFile but do not use it. In new FileInputStream(new File(dbPath)) you again create a new File from dbPath. But dbPath is never assigned to some String in the code you have shown.

Comment: If you have a `File` object, why are you messing around with InputStreams? See the [POI Documentation on why Files are better](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!